# KineticJS mouse position wrong after layer rotated

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

My demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/akuma/7NmXw/1/

1. First, draw something in the blue box.
2. Then, click the rotate button once.
3. After the box has been rotated, draw something again.
4. Finally the draw poisitoin was wrong.

How can I fix that, thanks!

## Code:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 500,
    height: 500
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
    width: 400,
    height: 400
});

var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    fill: '#00D2FF',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 5
});

layer.add(rect);
stage.add(layer);

$(document).on('click', '#rotateBtn', function () {
    var w = layer.getWidth(),
        h = layer.getHeight();
    layer.setOffset(w / 2, h / 2);
    layer.setPosition(w / 2, h / 2);
    layer.rotateDeg(90);
    layer.draw();
});

var points = [],
    drawing = false;

stage.on('mousedown', function () {
    drawing = true;

    var pos = stage.getMousePosition();
    points.push([pos.x, pos.y]);

    var line = new Kinetic.Line({
        id: 'line',
        points: [
            [pos.x, pos.y],
            [pos.x + 1, pos.y + 1]
        ],
        stroke: 'white',
        strokeWidth: 5,
        lineCap: 'round',
        lineJoin: 'round'
    });

    layer.add(line);
    layer.drawScene();
});

stage.on('mousemove', function () {
    if (!drawing) {
        return;
    }

    // Remove previous line
    layer.get('#line').remove();

    var pos = stage.getMousePosition();
    points.push([pos.x, pos.y]);

    // Redraw line
    var line = new Kinetic.Line({
        id: 'line',
        points: points,
        stroke: 'white',
        strokeWidth: 5,
        lineCap: 'round',
        lineJoin: 'round'
    });
    layer.add(line);
    layer.drawScene();
});

stage.on('mouseup', function () {
    drawing = false;
    points = [];
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Even after rotating, Kinetic will still give you un-rotated mouse coordinates**

That’s because you are asking for stage.getMousePosition and the stage is not rotated.

There is no method like layer.getMousePosition, so you’ll have to create one.

[image]

If you rotate your layer 90-degrees, you must also rotate stage's mouse coordinates by 90-degrees.

Here’s how you rotate the stage mouse position to match the layer rotation:

```
    // get the unrotated mouse position from Kinetic

    var pos=stage.getMousePosition();

    // rotate that point to match the layer rotation

    var x1 = rotationX 
              + (pos.x-rotationX)*rotationCos 
              + (pos.y-rotationY)*rotationSin;

    var y1 = rotationY 
              + (pos.y-rotationY)*rotationCos 
              - (pos.x-rotationX)*rotationSin;
```

Since you will be doing this math with each mousemove, you should pre-calculate the rotation values to maximize performance:

```
    // reset the current rotation information

    function setRotation(degrees){
        var radians=layer.getRotation();
        rotationX=layer.getOffsetX();
        rotationY=layer.getOffsetY();
        rotationCos=Math.cos(radians);
        rotationSin=Math.sin(radians);
    }
```

Also, a bit off-topic to your question, but...

Instead of removing / recreating a new line on every mousemove, you can “recycle” your existing line:

```
  // set the points property of the line to your updated points array

  line.setPoints(points);
```

Here’s code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/cQATv/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.5.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 500,
        height: 500
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({width:400,height:400});
    stage.add(layer);


    // vars to save the current rotation information
    var rotationX;
    var rotationY;
    var rotationCos;
    var rotationSin;
    setRotation(0);


    var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        fill: '#00D2FF',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 5
    });

    layer.add(rect);
    stage.add(layer);

    $(document).on('click', '#rotateBtn', function () {
        var w = layer.getWidth(),
            h = layer.getHeight();

        layer.setOffset(w / 2, h / 2);
        layer.setPosition(w / 2, h / 2);
        layer.rotateDeg(90);
        layer.draw();

        // set the info necessary to un-rotate the mouse position
        setRotation(layer.getRotationDeg())

    });

    var points = [],
        drawing = false;

    stage.on('mousedown', function () {
        drawing = true;

        // get the rotated mouse position
        pos=getPos();
        points.push([pos.x, pos.y]);

        var line = new Kinetic.Line({
            id: 'line',
            points: [
                [pos.x, pos.y],
                [pos.x + 1, pos.y + 1]
            ],
            stroke: 'white',
            strokeWidth: 5,
            lineCap: 'round',
            lineJoin: 'round'
        });

        layer.add(line);
        layer.drawScene();
    });

    stage.on('mousemove', function () {
        if (!drawing) {
            return;
        }

        // Remove previous line
        layer.get('#line').remove();

        // get the rotated mouse position
        var pos = getPos();
        points.push([pos.x, pos.y]);

        // Redraw line
        var line = new Kinetic.Line({
            id: 'line',
            points: points,
            stroke: 'white',
            strokeWidth: 5,
            lineCap: 'round',
            lineJoin: 'round'
        });
        layer.add(line);
        layer.drawScene();

    });

    stage.on('mouseup', function () {
        drawing = false;
        points = [];
    });


    // reset to the current rotation information
    function setRotation(degrees){
        var radians=layer.getRotation();
        rotationX=layer.getOffsetX();
        rotationY=layer.getOffsetY();
        rotationCos=Math.cos(radians);
        rotationSin=Math.sin(radians);
    }


    // rotate the stage mouse position
    // to match the layer rotation
    function getPos(x,y){

        // normal space, no adjustment necessary
        if(rotationCos==0){return;} 

        var pos=stage.getMousePosition();

        var x1 = rotationX 
                  + (pos.x-rotationX)*rotationCos 
                  + (pos.y-rotationY)*rotationSin;

        var y1 = rotationY 
                  + (pos.y-rotationY)*rotationCos 
                  - (pos.x-rotationX)*rotationSin;

        return({x:x1,y:y1});
    }


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <button id="rotateBtn">rotate</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works very good.
I used line.setPoints(points) before, but it makes the drawing a bit delay. I don't know why.